# Where does intellij idea save the local storage and preferences of libgdx (pc)

Tags: intellij-idea, libgdx

I started working with files, a simple operation of writing and reading files.

But i had an error when writing a file and now i have to fix it by hand.

Thats the problem, i don't know where is my file.
Also i would like to see the file i'm writing.

I am working with  intellij idea 2016 1.4, maybe the file is complied in a jar?

Yes, i know that clearing cache its an option.

> nothing here: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/File-handling

on the wiki link only talk about where you can find the ablolute path file but thats not my case. I get the file this way:

`this.resolver = Gdx.files.local(path + "item"+ String.valueOf(weaponNumber) + ".txt");
        String description = this.resolver.readString();`

So.. where is the file? thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the desktop version it saves the file in the assets folder inside your android module.

```
FileHandle file = Gdx.files.local("myfile.txt");
file.writeString("Test libGDX", false);
System.out.println(Gdx.files.getLocalStoragePath());
```

Output: `D:\Dropbox\Projetos\Outros\gdxTest\android\assets\`

The project folder in my computer is `gdxTest`.

In your case you have the `path` var so probably will be a folder inside assets folder.

But when you pack the desktop game into a jar file, the file will be created in the same folder where your game jar file is located. Usually `yourProject\desktop\build\libs`.

The difference is because when we configure the desktop project we set the *Working Directory* in the `yourProject\android\assets\` folder. So to Android Studio it is the local folder of your project.